# python linkedin oauth2 - where is http_api.py?

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get this example to work from https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin. I'm using his example. When I run this code. I don't get the `RETURN_URL` and `authorization_code` talked about in the example. I'm not sure why, I think it is because I'm not setting up the `HTTP API example` correctly. I can't find `http_api.py`, and when I visit `http://localhost:8080`, I get a "this site can't be reached".

```
from linkedin import linkedin

API_KEY = 'wFNJekVpDCJtRPFX812pQsJee-gt0zO4X5XmG6wcfSOSlLocxodAXNMbl0_hw3Vl'
API_SECRET = 'daJDa6_8UcnGMw1yuq9TjoO_PMKukXMo8vEMo7Qv5J-G3SPgrAV0FqFCd0TNjQyG'
RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
# Optionally one can send custom "state" value that will be returned from OAuth server
# It can be used to track your user state or something else (it's up to you)
# Be aware that this value is sent to OAuth server AS IS - make sure to encode or hash it
#authorization.state = 'your_encoded_message'
print authentication.authorization_url  # open this url on your browser
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
```

Comment: Please delete this API key and secret from your LinkedIn account! They're not supposed to be shared publicly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http_api.py` is [one of the examples provided in the package](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/tree/master/examples). This is an HTTP server that will handle the response from LinkedIn's OAuth end point, so you'll need to boot it up for the example to work.

As stated in the guide, you'll need to [execute that example file](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/blob/master/examples/http_api.py) to get the server working. Note you'll also need to supply the following environment variables: `LINKEDIN_API_KEY` and `LINKEDIN_API_SECRET`.

You can run the example file by downloading the repo and calling `LINKEDIN_API_KEY=yourkey LINKEDIN_API_SECRET=yoursecret python examples/http_api.py`. Note you'll need Python 3.4 for it to work.

Comment: OK, now when I do step 1. visit http://localhost:8080. I get `http://localhost:8080/code?error=invalid_scope&error_description=Your+application+has+not+been+authorized+for+the+scope+%22rw_nus%22#!` in the browser ... and `AssertionError: You must first get the authorization code` in python.

Comment: Did you visit the authorization URL given from the snipped you created?

Comment: yeah, what i showed you is the result of visiting the URL using the code created.

Comment: It's actually working, you just need to make sure you authorize the application for the permissions your app requires on LinkedIn.